# What's the difference between deque and list STL containers?

Tags: c++, list, stl, deque

What is the difference between the two? I mean the methods are all the same. So, for a user, they work identically.

Is that correct??

Comment: i am interested in iteration performance.. what is faster to ierate from beggining to end?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

From the (dated but still very useful) [SGI STL](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/) summary of [`deque`](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/Deque.html):

> A deque is very much like a vector: like vector, it is a sequence that supports random access to elements, constant time insertion and removal of elements at the end of the sequence, and linear time insertion and removal of elements in the middle.
>
> The main way in which deque differs from vector is that deque also supports constant time insertion and removal of elements at the beginning of the sequence. Additionally, deque does not have any member functions analogous to vector's capacity() and reserve(), and does not provide any of the guarantees on iterator validity that are associated with those member functions.

Here's the summary on [`list`](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/List.html) from the same site:

> A list is a doubly linked list. That is, it is a Sequence that supports both forward and backward traversal, and (amortized) constant time insertion and removal of elements at the beginning or the end, or in the middle. Lists have the important property that insertion and splicing do not invalidate iterators to list elements, and that even removal invalidates only the iterators that point to the elements that are removed. The ordering of iterators may be changed (that is, list::iterator might have a different predecessor or successor after a list operation than it did before), but the iterators themselves will not be invalidated or made to point to different elements unless that invalidation or mutation is explicit.

In summary the containers may have shared routines but *the time guarantees for those routines differ from container to container*. This is very important when considering which of these containers to use for a task: taking into account *how* the container will be most frequently used (e.g., more for searching than for insertion/deletion) goes a long way in directing you to the right container.

Comment: std::list also has the 'splice' method which lets you merge two lists together

Comment: Actually, the time guarantees are the _second_ most important feature of list.  The _most_ important feature of list is that you can add and remove elements and not invalidate your iterators!  In (almost?) every other STL container, every edit operation invalidates all your iterators - so to "delete matching items" you need to accumulate the matching items in one operation, and then delete them in another.  In a list, you can walk through it, remove and add as you wish, and never have to recalculate an iterator.

Comment: These are also the abstract differences, so measure reality for your case! Both list and deque have O(1) insertion/deletion, but don't forget that means k * O(1), and k has different values for list and deque. In my case, it took ten times longer to add an object to a list than a deque because list needed more calls to new/delete.  That will obviously vary based on which STL implementation you have.

Comment: Your answer says: for **deque**, insertion/removal at the beginning/end happens in constant time (and [std::deque document on cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque) says the same), and that for **list** happens in amortized constant time. However, aJ.'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1436418/10358768) says the opposite. As per my understanding, in the case of linked lists, insertion/removal at the beginning is constant, and that for the end is `O(n)` as it has to iterate through all the nodes. I'm confused here. Could you please elaborate? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I agree with Milan. List does NOT have constant time inserts.... how is there such a huge misunderstanding from so many people?

Comment: @LucasMumbo From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list): "std::list is a container that supports constant time insertion and removal of elements from anywhere in the container." In most cases, std::list is a doubly-linked list. A doubly linked list is a set of items, each with pointers to its neighboring items. If you have an iterator pointing to an item, you can insert a new item before or after it in constant time by changing a few pointers. Please read up on the relevant standards and algorithms before making incorrect comments.

Comment: @Milan std::deque is not necessarily contiguous. Usually it's implemented as a map of contiguous fixed-size arrays with some bookkeeping. This is best explained somewhat graphically, like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50959796). Hope that helps!

Answer (score 176):

Let me list down the differences:

- **Deque** manages its elements with a
  *dynamic array*, provides *random
  access*, and has almost the same
  interface as a vector.
- **List** manages its elements as a
  *doubly linked list* and does not
  provide *random access*.

---

- **Deque** provides Fast insertions and deletions at
  both the end and the beginning. Inserting and deleting elements in
  the middle is relatively slow because
  all elements up to either of both
  ends may be moved to make room or to
  fill a gap.
- In **List**, inserting and removing elements is fast at each position,
  including both ends.

---

- **Deque**: Any insertion or deletion of elements
  other than at the beginning or end
  invalidates all pointers, references,
  and iterators that refer to elements
  of the deque.
- **List**: Inserting and deleting elements does
  not invalidate pointers, references,
  and iterators to other elements.

---

**Complexity**

```
             Insert/erase at the beginning       in middle        at the end

Deque:       Amortized constant                  Linear           Amortized constant
List:        Constant                            Constant         Constant
```

Comment: @aJ: What is the difference between `constant` and `amortized constant`?

Comment: Operations in the long term behave as described. However, a single operation may take longer than specified. ex: to insert an element into a vector whose current capacity is  10 and size already 9 is constant, where as time is linear if capacity is 10 and size is also 10. Its because it has to allocate and  copy all the elements to new memory.

Comment: @aJ: How does deque provide random access? Also how is this structure implemented?

Comment: @Lazer - amortized constant happens when you have objects that allocate memory in advance. For example, when you define a vector or a deque, it will allocate some places in the memory ( lets say 1024). But now, if your vector or deque grows and you add more and more elements to it, (and therefore it reaches 1024 elements), it has to do something. It has to create a larger container, (maybe a container of 2048 units) + it also has to copy everything into that larger container. Therefor, it acts in constant time, until it reaches certain point (where you've to wait) until it has copied everythin

Comment: Your answer says: for **list**, insertion/removal at the beginning/end happens in constant time, and that for **Deque** happens in amortized constant time. However, as per my understanding, in the case of Linked lists, insertion/removal at the beginning is constant, and that for the end is O(n) as it has to iterate through all the nodes. On the other hand, fbrereto's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1436038/10358768) says a bit different and kinda opposite thing. Also, [std::deque doc on cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque) supports his answer for `std::deque`.

Comment: `Deque` is not always the same as `vector`. You can push_front and pop_front in a deque but vector only allows push_back and pop_back.

Comment: This answer is wrong about list having constant-time inserts and also provided 0 clarification on what 'random access' means. I hope some of the answers below are read instead.

Answer (score 18):

[`std::list`](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/List.html) is basically a doubly linked list.

[`std::deque`](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/Deque.html), on the other hand, is implemented more like `std::vector`.  It has constant access time by index, as well as insertion and removal at the beginning and end, which provides dramatically different performance characteristics than a list.

Answer (score 15):

I've made illustrations for the students in my C++ class.
This is based (loosely) on (my understanding of) the implementation in the GCC STL implementation (
https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/stl_deque.h and https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/stl_list.h)

### Double-ended queue

[image: Illustration of std::deque]

Elements in the collection are stored in memory blocks. The number of elements per block depends on the size of the element: the bigger the elements, the fewer per block. The underlying hope is that if the blocks are of a similar size no matter the type of the elements, that should help the allocator most of the time.

You have an array (called a map in the GCC implementation) listing the memory blocks. All memory blocks are full except the first one which may have room at the beginning and the last which may have room at the end. The map itself is filled from the center outwards. This is how, contrarily to a `std::vector`, insertion at both ends can be done in constant time. Similarly to a `std:::vector`, random access is possible in constant time, but requires two indirections instead of one. Similarly to `std::vector` and contrarily to `std::list`, removing or inserting elements in the middle is costly because you have to reorganize a large part of the datastructure.

### Doubly-linked list

[image: Illustration of a std::list]

Doubly-linked list are perhaps more usual. Every element is stored in its own memory block, allocated independently from the other elements. In each block, you have the element's value and two pointers: one to the previous element, one to the next element. It makes it very easy to insert element at any position in the list, or even to move a subchain of elements from one list to another (an operation called *splicing*): you just have to update the pointers at the beginning and end of the insertion point. The downside is that to find one element by its index, you have to walk the chain of pointers, so random access has a linear cost in the numbers of elements in the list.

Answer (score 10):

Another important guarantee is the way each different container stores its data in memory:

- A vector is a single contiguous memory block.
- A deque is a set of linked memory blocks, where more than one element is stored in each memory block.
- A list is a set of elements dispersed in memory, i.e.: only one element is stored per memory "block".

Note that the deque was designed to *try to* balance the advantages of both vector and list without their respective drawbacks. It is a specially interesting container in memory limited platforms, for example, microcontrollers.

The memory storage strategy is often overlooked, however, it is frequently one of the most important reasons to select the most suitable container for a certain application.

Answer (score 5):

No.  A deque only supports O(1) insertion and deletion at the front and back.  It may, for example, be implemented in a vector with wrap-around.  Since it also guarantees O(1) random access, you can be sure it's not using (just) a doubly linked list.

Answer (score 4):

Among eminent differences between `deque` and `list`

- For `deque` :

  Items stored side by side;

  Optimized for adding datas from two sides (front, back);

  Elements indexed by numbers (integers).

  Can be browsed by iterators and even by element's index.

  Time access to data is faster.
- For `list`

  Items stored "randomly" in the memory;

  Can be browsed only by iterators;

  Optimized for insertion and removal in the middle.

  Time access to data is slower, slow to iterate, due to its very poor spatial locality.

  Handles very well large elements

You can check also the following [Link](https://baptiste-wicht.com/posts/2012/12/cpp-benchmark-vector-list-deque.html), which compares the performance between the two STL containers (with std::vector)

Hope i shared some useful informations.

Comment: how is list "Optimized for insertion and removal in the middle"? Where did you get this??

Answer (score 3):

The performance differences have been explained well by others.  I just wanted to add that similar or even identical interfaces are common in object-oriented programming -- part of the general methodology of writing object-oriented software.  You should IN NO WAY assume that two classes work the same way simply because they implement the same interface, any more than you should assume that a horse works like a dog because they both implement attack() and make_noise().

Answer (score 1):

Here's a proof-of-concept code use of list, unorded map that gives O(1) lookup and O(1) exact LRU maintenance. Needs the (non-erased) iterators to survive erase operations. Plan to use in a O(1) arbitrarily large software managed cache for CPU pointers on GPU memory. Nods to the Linux O(1) scheduler (LRU <-> run queue per processor). The unordered_map has constant time access via hash table.

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <list> 
#include <unordered_map>  
using namespace std; 

struct MapEntry {
  list<uint64_t>::iterator LRU_entry;
  uint64_t CpuPtr;
};
typedef unordered_map<uint64_t,MapEntry> Table;
typedef list<uint64_t> FIFO;
FIFO  LRU;        // LRU list at a given priority 
Table DeviceBuffer; // Table of device buffers

void Print(void){
  for (FIFO::iterator l = LRU.begin(); l != LRU.end(); l++) {
    std::cout<< "LRU    entry "<< *l << "   :    " ;
    std::cout<< "Buffer entry "<< DeviceBuffer[*l].CpuPtr <<endl;
  }  
}
int main() 
{ 

  LRU.push_back(0);
  LRU.push_back(1);
  LRU.push_back(2);
  LRU.push_back(3);
  LRU.push_back(4);

  for (FIFO::iterator i = LRU.begin(); i != LRU.end(); i++) {
    MapEntry ME = { i, *i}; 
    DeviceBuffer[*i] = ME;
  }

  std::cout<< "************ Initial set of CpuPtrs" <<endl;
  Print();

  {
    // Suppose evict an entry - find it via "key - memory address uin64_t" and remove from 
    // cache "tag" table AND LRU list with O(1) operations
    uint64_t key=2;
    LRU.erase(DeviceBuffer[2].LRU_entry);
    DeviceBuffer.erase(2);
  }

  std::cout<< "************ Remove item 2 " <<endl;
  Print();

  { 
    // Insert a new allocation in both tag table, and LRU ordering wiith O(1) operations
    uint64_t key=9;
    LRU.push_front(key); 
    MapEntry ME = { LRU.begin(), key };
    DeviceBuffer[key]=ME;
  }

  std::cout<< "************ Add item 9  " <<endl;
  Print();

  std::cout << "Victim "<<LRU.back()<<endl;
}
```

Comment: Did you post this in the right place? This doesn't answer the question.