# Traverse multi-dimensional array without recursion (while loops)

Tags: php

I have seen the implemented before but cannot recall how...

Has anyone solved this problem before and care to share the implementation of a tree traversal algorithm that DOES NOT use recursion but a while and a for loop (or similar)???

Comment: how do you want to traverse the tree?

Comment: depending on the method, using either a queue (for Breadth-First) or a stack (for Depth-First) will do

Comment: Also, a few implementation details would be nice. Just traverse, print, count, etc?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5278580/non-recursive-depth-first-search-algorithm

Comment: This problem is one of those ones that's intrinsically easier solved with recursion.  If you did it iteratively you'd need a data structure to keep track of the position in the tree.  A recursive solution would basically work as a stack that keeps track of the location on the tree (assuming depth-first), so a recursive solution could be mimicked with a stack.

Comment: @Dany: That is essentially the answer I was looking for to confirm my suspicions :)