# How to write a non recursive java function

Tags: java

how to write a non-recursive java function that computes the depth of a node in a tree(not binary) given that node

```
 public int depth(Node node) {
    int depth = 0;
    while (node != root) {
       node =node.parent;
       depth++;
    }
    return depth;
}
```

this works for binary trees but what about if it is not binary

Comment: This code will work for any __tree__

Comment: it's a tree. In a tree, a node has only one parent (as per definition of a tree), so it does not matter if the tree is binary or not.

Comment: Any recursive algorithm uses internal stack call and can be easily rewritten to non-recursive one. So, you could implement something like [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5278667/2487403) but applied to your problem.

Comment: Any "rooted" tree.  Any tree can be made "rooted" by designating one vertex as the root.  Then the parent of vertex A is the unique vertex B, one step closer to the root.  (From any vertex there is a unique path to the root.)

Comment: so the concept is the same, thank you very much for the clarification

Comment: You should ideally override hashCode() and equals() for the Node class and use that for comparison.