# Non-recursive Depth First Search using Matlab Function Block in Simulink for tree

Tags: algorithm, matlab, tree, depth-first-search, non-recursive

this is my first post on Stack Overflow. I really admire the site and all the users who help the others code a lot. Hopfully I can get some help from you:)

The problem I have met can be described as follows:

1. Start from a given node(root node);
2. Calculate the children of the node and store them(the number of the children is not known before calculating);
3. At the leaf node, calculate the value of the leaf using 'evaluate function'.
4. When all the leaves are evaluated, choose the leaf node which has largest/smallest value and get the data stored in this leaf's grandfather(child of root) as showed in picture.

Process of traverse and build a tree:

[image: Process of traverse and build a tree]

As the 'evaluate function' can only be applied at leaf node, I think depth-first search is suitable here. What's more, the MATLAB Function Block in Simulink **doesn't support calling function recursively**. So I think using Stack to store the node is a good way.

According to the excellent answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5278580/non-recursive-depth-first-search-algorithm), the logic is quite clear and straight forward. Code from [Gumbo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/53114/gumbo)

```
stack.push(root)
while !stack.isEmpty() do
  node = stack.pop()
  for each node.childNodes do
    stack.push(stack)
  endfor
// …
endwhile
```

But I met some problems when I implemented the DFS algorithm:

1. As Adjacency matrix wastes a lot of memory, I tried to use adjacency list to represent the tree. But I didn't even find a pseudo code **using adjacency list to implement DFS algorithm**. Could someone help me?
2. How can I update the tree when new nodes a calculated from parent(adding nodes)?
3. Should I let the children inherit the data from the grandfather(children of root) to spare the tracing-back-step? Is there other way to solve 4th step of the process?

Comment: Are you calculating the children of all of the nodes, not just the root? If so, then I don't see why you need an adjacency list/matrix at all; just push the calculated nodes onto the stack.

Comment: @beaker You are right! In my case I don't even need a list to mark the nodes that are visited. A stack can fullfill all I need. Thank you!