# std::deque or std::list

Tags: c++, performance, list, deque

I am using `push_front()` and `push_back()` only. Thus, I do not incur any other cost of using `insert()` or `remove()`.

I know both containers offer `O(1)` complexity for each of these functions, `deque`s having amortized constant time compared to `list`s having constant time.

But I want to know which time is less than the other, if there is, at all.

Comment: I don't suppose you've tried timing it...?

Comment: Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436020/c-stl-containers-whats-the-difference-between-deque-and-list

Comment: How do you access the elements? Do you do random access or sequential access?

Comment: I was more after reasoning behind it, not benchmarking code.

Comment: See this concise post too: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1436418/341744

Comment: I had seen that @monkey thank you, it just said both were fast though and no more.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Not sure how to answer your question.  You seem to want us to write a benchmark program that you could easily write yourself.  So instead of doing that, I'll just state this:

- With a `list`, every item you push will incur a memory allocation.
- With a `deque`, large blocks are allocated at once.

Given that memory allocation is normally slow, I would expect the `deque` to out-perform list.

If you push or pop many items at once, this will be especially true, as cache locality comes into play.

Of course, you could write an allocator on the list to use a memory pool.  Then you might get better performance.

So with these hypotheses in mind, go away and *measure* it, and if you want to discuss the results, that would be the time to ask a question.

Comment: this is it, thank you.
Lists allocate memory on the fly.
Deques allocate a block.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Whenever it comes to performance, it's a bad idea to "guess" (or ask on the internet, which is slightly better than guessing, but only somewhat), and always best to measure the two options - in this case, just do a loop, and push_back or push_front enough things to make it realistic [you may want to make it more realistic and run most of what your code does, and do that in a loop enough times to make it last enough to measure the time - it's often more realistict than adding a bazillion values to a `list`/`deque` and then finding that "when you have to swap out, it gets very slow!"].